# How to calculate the eigenvalues of nonhomogeneous system of LDE?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

The system

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dx}{dt}&=-8 - 4 y + 2 x y,
\\
\dfrac{dy}{dt}&=-x^2 + 4 y^2.
\end{align}

I have linearized it for one of the singularity point(-1,-2):

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dx}{dt}&=-2x+4,
\\
\dfrac{dy}{dt}&=4x-8y.
\end{align}

The problem is that I got a free member(don't know how it in English) - "4" in the first equation(i.e. $-2x+0y+4$).

---

user247327 noticed that my linearization was wrong, so I provide a linearization respectively to the second singularity point(4,2)

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dx}{dt}&=4x+4y-24,
\\
\dfrac{dy}{dt}&=-8x+16y+60.
\end{align}

Equations have -24 and 60 free members.
The equation for lamdas(eigenvalues), I've found is

\begin{align}
\lambda_{1,2}=\dfrac{a+d}{2}+-\sqrt{\dfrac{(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)}{4}}
\end{align}

where a,b,c,d are the coefficient of the linear equations.

Please, explain what should I do in such cases? The goal I want to reach is to determine type of the singularity points of nonlinear system.

Answer (score 1):

Your "$\frac{dx}{dt}= -2x+ 4$"should be $\frac{dx}{dt}= -2x+ 4y$.  And if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, we must have $\frac{dx}{dt}= -2x+ 4y= \lambda x$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}= 4x- 8y= \lambda y$.  The two equations, $-2x+ 4y= \lambda x$ and $4x- 8y= \lambda y$ are equivalent to $(-2- \lambda)x+ 4y= 0$ and $4x- (8+ \lambda)y= 0$.  Those equations have the obvious *trivial* solution $x= y= 0$.  An "eigenvalue" for this problem is a value of $\lambda$ such that this equation has other, non-trivial solutions.

This set of equations can also be written as the matrix equation, $$\begin{bmatrix}-2- \lambda & 4 \\ 4 & -8- \lambda \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$  IF that matrix is invertible we could easily solve it by multiplying both sides by that inverse to get the *trivial* solution $$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$  There will be a non-trivial solution only if that matrix is NOT invertible which means that its determinant must be 0.

That is, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue only if $$\left|\begin{array}{cc}-2- \lambda & 4 \\ 4 & -8- \lambda \end{array}\right|= (-2- \lambda)(-8- \lambda)- 16= \lambda^2+ 10\lambda= \lambda(\lambda+ 10)= 0.$$  That is, the eigenvalues are 0 and -10.

Comment: Wait a moment, the lambdas formula I pinned is incorrect?

Comment: Actually, the task I need to do is to determine type of the singularity point, and as I understood couple of lamdas describe it

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: If I just add to the coeff matrix the free members, it wouldn't be a square matrix, I can't get the determinant. Maybe I should add to system two equations with free members and then calculate determinant of the 4x4 matrix? But it will be 3x4 matrix.